# I can't Access specifiec website

Tags: firefox, internet

I can't access to a website.
My internet works correctly. for access that site i should restart wifi modem every time.
I get this error.

```
The connection has timed out

The server at www.arazoilco.com is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Comment: The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

Comment: No, I tried with ping.eu . everything is right.

Comment: you try to access that website

Comment: I can connect fine. What country are you accessing it from? It's possible you're government is blocking this page.

Comment: I'm in Islamic republic of Iran. It's my website. But server in Germany. I could access to that with changing ip.

Comment: If you can access the domain when you change the ip address then your service provider is blocking the ip address.

Answer (score -2):

The website's servers must be down. They must be doing maintenance of some sort, or they could be getting DDoS'd by someone.